Authorisation error reading json file in MAUI C# net8 mac
I am working on a .NET 8 MAUI project. At some point I need to retrieve a JSON file for internationalization. But it's not working even though the file is in the correct location.
The error I get is that I don't have permission to access this file. I added permissions to my Info.plist file, but nothing has changed. I'm actually working on visual studio code because visual studio closed recently. It's not about just only json file, I try to open or read other file and it doesn't work.
It's what I add to my file :
    <key>NSFileAccessUsageDescription</key>
    <string>L'application a besoin d'accéder à tous les fichiers et dossiers de votre ordinateur pour fonctionner correctement et gérer vos fichiers personnels.</string>

    <!-- Autres autorisations d'accès spécifiques aux dossiers -->
    <key>NSDocumentsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>L'application a besoin d'accéder au dossier Documents pour stocker et lire vos fichiers.</string>
    <key>NSDesktopFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>L'application a besoin d'accéder au dossier Bureau pour gérer les fichiers que vous y avez placés.</string>
    <key>NSDownloadsFolderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>L'application a besoin d'accéder au dossier Téléchargements pour gérer et lire les fichiers que vous avez téléchargés.</string>


I have all autorisation on my pc for the project

The problem is from the project not outside

Entitlements.plist is correct

I had autorisation on my json file

error : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/Users/user/Projects/ProjetSAE/equipe1b/Resources/Localization/fr.json' is denied.

json path : /Users/user/Projects/ProjetSAE/equipe1b/Resources/Localization/fr.json

extract of the code :


using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8)) { jsonContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync(); }

Path to open the file :
string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); filePath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "Resources", "Localization", $"{languageCode}.json");

When I try to use it on Windows it works but not on Mac



Where is the file located?  What path are you using to open it?  Where is the relevant code?  What error or exception do you get?  Please read [ask] for guidance on the basic information you should include when posting

the json file path : /Users/user/Projects/ProjetSAE/equipe1b/Resources/Localization/fr.json

please [edit] your question to include the requested information.  It sounds like the "file" you are trying to read is actually an embedded resource.

what is the Build Action of your json file set to?  Also, try using a relative path instead of an absolute path

Thank you i found it, it was because of my Build Action. I tried EmbeddedResource and it works. I also used relative path instead of an absolute path

You may try placing the json file in Resource/Raw folder and  access it using OpenAppPackageFileAsync. See File system helpers.
